# Use Sed to get string between two strings and split

Tags: sed

What's wrong with the following sed expression? I'm trying to get everything between `topic =` and the `first semi-colon` that's encountered and then split to result using comma as a delimiter.

```
sed "s/oc.diffusion.topic = ""(.*)"""";/\1/g"| sed "s/$/,/"
```

This is the test string:

```
   xchangeCommission = true;oc.diffusion.topic = "Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/topic,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*/repub_OC//,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/repub_OC/all,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188//,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188/all";var SKY_TRA
```

Comment: _You_ tell us what is wrong. Unexpected results? No results at all? An error?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```c
sed 's/[^"]*"//;s/".*//;y/,/\n/'
```

or

```c
awk '!/;/' RS='[",]'
```

Result

```
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/topic
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*/repub_OC//
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/repub_OC/all
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188//
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188/all
```

Comment: What if there are no `;` before and after text OP like.  What if there are `;` within the text?  Both this will then file.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed

```
sed  's/.*oc.diffusion.topic = "\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' file

Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/topic,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*/repub_OC//,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/repub_OC/all,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188//,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188/all
```

#### Explanation

- `[^"]*` will maek the command easily to get all chars without double quote.

or using grep

```
grep -Po "(?<=topic = \")[^\"]*" file
```

#### After see the accept answer, I now know what you expect.

```
sed  's/,/\n/g;s/.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/' file

Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/topic
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*/repub_OC//
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/repub_OC/all
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188//
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188/all
```

Comment: The grep command works, but I had to escape the two 'double-quote' characters by doubling them up as I'm doing this in a bat file. It still won't split the string on the commas, though. The following worked: `grep -Po "(?<=topic = "")[^\""]*" source.txt | tr "," "\n"`

Comment: the first sed and grep command generated the result to get the content between double quote. The last sed does all the jobs (include split the string on the commas), did you try the second sed command?

Comment: Tried it. It won't work. I need to find out the difference between running this in DOS vs Linux and shell vs bat. There's a convention in escaping characters that I don't know.

Comment: `In DOS` do you mean in windows? I did the test in CYGWIN in windows. What sed do you have? sed for windows, or sed in CYGWIN?

Comment: It' GNUWIN or GNUUTILS Sed, I think. It says `GNU sed version 4.2.1`.

Comment: ic, that's sed for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). Recommend to install CYGWIN, not sed for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Since the text you have is the only text between quotes you can use this simple `awk`

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' file
Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/topic,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_.*/repub_OC//,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/market_1758201893/bet_all/repub_OC/all,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188//,Oddschecker/category_27/event_9945/subevent_63289835/fixture_401188/all
```